# IE 11 - user-select override value not being applied on child elements

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

For a task, the product owner wants to disable most HTML elements from being highlighted via `Ctrl-A`.  The way I'm doing this is to set

```
body {
  -{$prefix}-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

div.element-to-select {
  -{$prefix}-user-select: all;
  user-select: all;
}
```

I've also made up a codepen at http://codepen.io/daredevil82/pen/zxPzbJ to demonstrate.  In this example, when mouse focus is on the white area, a `Ctrl-A` press will have the **Select** text highlighted but the **No Select** text will remain un-highlighted in Firefox 35+ and Chrome, but both elements will not be selected in IE 11.

Is there a way around this behavior for IE?

Comment: Be aware that [`user-select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) is non-standard and is not on a standards track. A similar property `user-focus` was proposed in [early drafts of a predecessor of css3-ui](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-css3-userint-20000216) but was rejected by the working group.

Comment: Agreed, but the fact of the existence of vendor prefixes for FF, webkit and IE speaks to vendors implementing their own solutions to the property.    In addition, it is common for CSS to override alter properties of child elements to vary from their parent's settings.  This convention appears to be broken with IE.

Comment: I actually can't reproduce the issue...clicking around and pressing ctrl-A does nothing to select the text. (Win7)

Comment: If you're on IE and Ctrl-A selects nothing, that is the issue.  You should be able to highlight the Select text on the second line.

Comment: @Jason Oh. Not what you said; "*but both elements will be selected in IE 11*"

Comment: ack.. that was something important!  Thanks for the catch; its been fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Working Draft User Interface for CSS3 defined [`user-select`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-css3-userint-20000216#user-select) like this:

> This property is not inherited, but it does affect children in the
>   same way that `display: none` does, it limits it. That is if an element
>   is `user-select: none`, it doesn't matter what the `user-select` value
>   is of its children, the element's contents or it's childrens contents
>   cannot be selected.

Firefox implemented `-moz-user-select: none` according to that draft; and also implemented `-moz-user-select: -moz-none`, which allowed selection to be re-enabled on sub-elements using `-moz-user-select: text`.

However, starting with Firefox 21, `-moz-user-select: none` behaves like `-moz-user-select: -moz-none`, due to [Bug 816298](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=816298):

> Our `-moz-user-select: none` behaves as proposed in the css3-userint TR
>   but WebKit, IE, and Opera's `-XXX-user-select: none` behave like
>   `-moz-user-select: -moz-none`.

Not sure if the bug is wrong and IE also followed the proposed spec, or if IE changed the behavior later. But now IE seems to be the only major browser which follows it.

However, you can't rely on that draft. The User interface for CSS3 module has been superseded by [CSS Basic User Interface Module Level 3 (CSS3 UI)](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/), which doesn't include `user-select`.

Therefore, since `user-select` is no longer standard, implementators won't probably change their implementations in order to have a common behavior among different browsers.